# Is there any material which is non magnet & conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors

Magnetic materials and conductors

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by "non magnet". Copper, for example, is an excellent conductor and has negligible magnetic properties from a practical point of view. On the other hand, if you mean a conductor which shows no response to a changing magnetic field i.e. no induced current, then the answer is no.

Comment: I mean a non magnetic material

Comment: @NarayanaRavuri Non-magnetic material has a really vague definition. Could be more precise on what you mean by non-magnetic? Copper is diamagnetic, which means, it is not attracted towards magnetic materials rather gets  repelled very slightly.